# Textfield onchange validation

Tags: java, swing, validation, textfield

I'm using the following code to write a Loan Calculator, but when I try to validate the user's input, I'm having trouble getting the setText to run. I'm not getting any compile errors, it just isn't working. I have the following code:

```
public class LoanCalculator extends JFrame {
  // Create text fields for interest rate,
// year, loan amount, monthly payment, and total payment
private JTextField jtfAnnualInterestRate = new JTextField("5");
private JTextField jtfNumberOfYears = new JTextField("10");
private JTextField jtfLoanAmount = new JTextField("10000");
private JTextField jtfMonthlyPayment = new JTextField("106.07");
private JTextField jtfTotalPayment = new JTextField("12727.86");

// Create a Compute Payment button
private JButton jbtClear = new JButton("Reset Fields");

public LoanCalculator() {
// Panel p1 to hold labels and text fields
JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 2));
p1.add(new JLabel("Annual Interest Rate"));
p1.add(jtfAnnualInterestRate);
p1.add(new JLabel("Number of Years"));
p1.add(jtfNumberOfYears);
p1.add(new JLabel("Loan Amount"));
p1.add(jtfLoanAmount);
p1.add(new JLabel("Monthly Payment"));
p1.add(jtfMonthlyPayment);
p1.add(new JLabel("Total Payment"));
p1.add(jtfTotalPayment);
p1.setBorder(new
TitledBorder("Enter loan amount, interest rate, and year"));
jtfTotalPayment.setEditable(false);
jtfMonthlyPayment.setEditable(false);

// Panel p2 to hold the button
JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
p2.add(jbtClear);

// Add the panels to the frame
add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

// Register listeners
jbtClear.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
jtfAnnualInterestRate.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocListener());
jtfNumberOfYears.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocListener());
jtfLoanAmount.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocListener());
}

/** Handle textfield changes */
class DocListener implements DocumentListener {
 public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { validate(); }
 public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { }
 public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { }

 public void validate() {
     //get values from text fields
     double interest = Double.parseDouble(jtfAnnualInterestRate.getText());
 int year = Integer.parseInt(jtfNumberOfYears.getText());
 double loanAmt = Double.parseDouble(jtfLoanAmount.getText());
 Loan loan = new Loan(interest, year, loanAmt);


 //validate field values and shift focus if needed
 if (! (interest >= 1 && interest <= 10)){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
        "interest must be between 1 and 10 percent");
     jtfAnnualInterestRate.setText("5");                   //THIS DOESN'T RUN
     jtfAnnualInterestRate.requestFocus(true);
 }       
 //display monthly and total payments
 else {
      jtfMonthlyPayment.setText(String.format("%.2f", 
                          loan.getMonthlyPayment()));
      jtfTotalPayment.setText(String.format("%.2f", 
                  loan.getTotalPayment()));
 }
 }
}

/** Handle the Reset button Code not included */
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
 LoanCalculator frame = new LoanCalculator();
 frame.pack();
 frame.setTitle("LoanCalculator");
 Dimension screenSize =
   Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
 int screenWidth = screenSize.width;
int screenHeight = screenSize.height;
// Locate the upper-left corner at (x, y)
int x =  3 * (screenWidth - frame.getWidth()) / 4;
int y = (screenHeight - frame.getHeight()) /2;
frame.setLocation(x, y);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 3):

You can't mutate a JTextComponent inside of its own DocumentListener, at least not directly. I know of two possible solutions:

1) queue the text change onto the EDT inside of a Runnable:

```
if (!(interest >= 1 && interest <= 10)) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "interest must be between 1 and 10 percent");
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         jtfAnnualInterestRate.setText("5"); // THIS DOESN'T RUN
         jtfAnnualInterestRate.requestFocus(true);
      }
   });
```

2) Use a DocumentFilter

---

**Edit**
Note regarding your question:

> it just isn't working. I have the following code:

It's doing more than "isn't working". It is in fact throwing an important exception, one that describes exactly what your code is doing wrong and *where*:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.writeLock(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setText(Unknown Source)
    at pkg.LoanCalculator$DocListener.validate(LoanCalculator.java:78) // your numbers will be different
    at pkg.LoanCalculator$DocListener.insertUpdate(LoanCalculator.java:58) // ditto
```

Next time you ask a similar question, you'll probably want to post the informative exception stacktrace with your question. It will help us immenselfy.

---

**Edit 2**
Also next time, try to post only code necessary for compilation and relevant to your problem. For instance all you need to post is your JTextField, your DocumentListener and display it in a simple JOptionPane. i.e.,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class LoanCalcSscce {
   protected static final double MIN_INTEREST = 0;
   protected static final double MAX_INTEREST = 10;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final JTextField jtfAnnualInterestRate = new JTextField("5");
      jtfAnnualInterestRate.getDocument().addDocumentListener(
            new DocumentListener() {

               @Override
               public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                  validate(e);
               }

               @Override
               public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                  validate(e);
               }

               @Override
               public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                  validate(e);
               }

               public void validate(DocumentEvent e) {
                  final Document doc = e.getDocument();
                  try {
                     String text = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()).trim();
                     double interest = Double.parseDouble(text);

                     if (!(interest >= MIN_INTEREST && interest <= MAX_INTEREST)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                              "interest must be between 1 and 10 percent");
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                           public void run() {
                              jtfAnnualInterestRate.setText("5");
                              jtfAnnualInterestRate.requestFocus(true);
                           }
                        });
                     }
                  } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                     e1.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                     // inform user and set interest to baseline.
                  }
               }
            });
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jtfAnnualInterestRate);
   }
}
```

And we'd have a much easier time analyzing your code and helping you to solve it. This is called an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

---

**Edit 3**
For my money, I wouldn't validate my input in a DocumentListener because then it may try to validate when the input is not yet complete. I'd do all my validation when the user decides to submit the data by pressing the submit (or whatever you call it) button. In other words, I'd validate in an ActinoListener.  Exceptions: if the input must be numeric only, or only lower-case letters, or something else where it is OK and important to validate partial input, I'd validate that in a DocumentFilter.

---

**Edit 4**
As MadProgrammer suggests in comment, also have a serious look at using an InputVerifier as a nice way to verify input when the user leaves the input field (here the JTextField): [InputVerifier tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification)

Comment: [InputVerifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html), better then using focus listeners, but agree with everything else

Comment: @MadProgrammer: thanks! I've edited my answer to add this information.

Comment: And my vote still goes to a pimped version of the `JFormattedTextField` which can provide immediate user feed-back and has built-in validation.